# Fold all code (or other ways of dealing with large files)?

Tags: sublimetext3, organization, code-organization

I have huge files with lots of code in them, and they are all nicely structured, and nicely commented, so folding all the top level blocks works great for me. That way I can see the comment before a code block, expand it when I need it to make changes, and also quickly get to a block near the end of a file without "too much hassle".

I know there is a plugin for Sublime text that remembers folded code after the file had been closed, so that I don't get everything unfolded when I open it again. And that is also great.

What isn't great, is the fact that when I want to jump to a method by using Ctrl+R, Sublime will unfold all code that is even remotely related to my search query, even if I end up not going to the suggested method, or simply press `Esc` after having intended to search for a method. So by using that shortcut (which is an extremely useful one), I will quickly end up with everything being unfolded again.

What I would want is for Sublime to either fold the code back if I ended up not going to any of those regions that it unfolded for the purpose of searching, or a keyboard shortcut that allows me to Fold all. And by fold all, I mean go through all the top-level blocks and fold only those, not fold the entire file (as it would if I did `Select all` and then `Fold`).

I hope my question is clear, I'm not sure if I explained myself well, but I will edit if necessary.

Alternatively, do you have any other tips for hopping around methods in large files?

Comment: Have you tried using smaller files? What's the point of having 27 classes and 473 methods in the same file? Essentially all languages support includes, imports, and the like.

Comment: Well in this case the point is having to download a single Javascript file.

Comment: In that case, you should be using some sort of build system (there are many out there) to join your commented, indented, descriptive code files into a single minified file for delivery.